# Image Classification for watermarks with poor results

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, image-recognition, binary-classification

Just starting learning things about tensorflow and NN.
As an exercise I decided to create a dataset of images, watermarked and not, in order to binary classify these. First of all, the dataset ( you can see it [here](https://www.kaggle.com/felicepollano/watermarked-not-watermarked-images) ) was created artificially by me applying some random watermarks.
First doubt, in the dataset I don't have both images one watermarked and one not, would be better to have?
Second, frustrating: model stand on 0.5 accuracy, so it just produce random output :(
Model I tried is this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(1,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
```

and then compiled as this:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Here below the fit:

```
history = model.fit(train_data,
                              validation_data=valid_data,
                              steps_per_epoch=100,
                              epochs=15,
                              validation_steps=50,
                              verbose=2)
```

As for any other details, code is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/felicepollano/starter-watermarked-not-watermarked-e54da0df-f).
I already checked for technical issues, I'm pretty sure image enter properly, train and validation dataset are 80/20, about 12K images for training. However accuracy bounches up and down around .5 while fitting. How can I improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well probably the response is that previous approach was a little naive.
I managed to fave some interesting result [with this kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/felicepollano/starter-watermarked-not-watermarked-e54da0df-f?scriptVersionId=44273914) that allow me to have an **accuracy of 0.969**  and a **validation accuracy of 0.931**.
Model I used is based on **ResNet50** with the following additional layers ( and the last one just for binary classification ):

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
```

Even if the net is already trained, I trained each layer again otherwise I did not have any sensible accuracy.

Training history is like this:

[image]

Still far to be really good, but progress.